# Graphics card recommendation, Dell PowerEdge R210 & CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, graphic-card

I have server with displays and a keyboard-mouse for displaying network map status and for use as a shell and virtual console in my server room. Need a recent video card that is > $100 that can support the hardware requirements. I do not need to do any heavy rendering, but multiple open windows and graphics on Gnome2x desktop.

I am required to use CentOS 6.5. =-/
My hardware:
Dell PowerEdge R210
- Intel Core (i3 or i5, family6 model 37 stepping 2) 1.2GHz
- 4GB DDR3 ram
- 1 available PCIx slot (full size/height, it is on a riser/right-angle card)
2x Apple Cinema HD 30" (M9179LL/A)

I have tried an ATI HD3450 and several similar older cards. Double screwed with older ATI; the chipsets are unsupported by current drivers (proprietary and ElRepo), and the legacy drivers do not support current Xorg packages (so I have to downgrade etc. ad naseum).

I have also tried a Geforce 7300 GT that I cannibalized from an old Mac Pro. Nouveau driver does not like/recognize the card, NVidia driver install script says the adapter is not initialized (bad card? incompatible with Dell hw?)

I'm done with old used hardware. Any suggestions on a decent, inexpensive, *currently supported* video adapter that will drive these two displays at native 2560x1600 resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only meaningful advantage in buying an ATI or Nvidia card is to use them for hardware accelerated **[OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opengl) rendering**, generally in 3D.  Otherwise they are just a waste of power and money.

The only thing which makes use of openGL on a general purpose GUI desktop are some DE specific special effects such as a "spinning cube" to switch workspaces, etc.  Generally these are not super heavy and work fine with software acceleration, so having a proper 3D card is not going to matter much in this context.

Just go buy *anything* (checking the chip and linux driver status first).  It does not matter.  Again, do waste money (and hassles with proprietary drivers) getting a gaming/CAD card from ATI/Nvidia.  That is competently and totally pointless.  *Anything* made in the past 5 years (in fact, the past 10-15 years) will be just fine.  It does not even particularly matter how much video memory it has on board.